# Close button in popup not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I use this code to close popup but this is not working.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: perhaps more code is required to assist you.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Do you have a public URL so we could actually see the problem?

Comment: Made a fiddle from W3 including your code-snippet in OP: https://jsfiddle.net/69e01ju5/3/ Your code works fine... W3 example is the first x-button, Mosh Feu is second and the answer below is the third. The problem must be located elsewhere... Show some more code so we can actually help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with this- this is from one of my modals and it works:

my code

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
```

this is slightly different from your existing code - slightly different ARIA content - but the main difference is that I know this works. So if you replace yours with mine and it still doesn't function - its not the cause of the problem:

old code

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This is no difference from what he Mosh already has written... Is it?

Comment: thanks @chrisv - good point - but it is slightly different with the ARIA content and spans, and I have amended my post to show it, but the point is that it is a functioning section of code for closing the modal and it the OP replaces it and the modal still doesn't close fom this - then its a different issue than the close button causing the problem.

Comment: @chrisv - nice fiddle! demonstrates that the code listed is not the issue for the OP. :) and your fiddle wasn't there when I posted and I am afraid I don't know how to make a fiddle